# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'null' On Nullable column

Tags: laravel, axios, laravel-7

My application has a weird error when i'm trying to update some nullable integer value to null through laravel.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'null' for column 'next' at row 1 (SQL: update `questions` set `content` = <strong>Kulitmu sering terlihat/terasa:</strong>, `next` = null, `order` = 9, `questions`.`updated_at` = 2021-02-14 17:18:29 where `id` = 9 and `questions`.`deleted_at` is null)
```

I've tried to execute the SQL on the error directly on SQL console, and it has no problem, the update is accepting null value for the nullable integer column, so I think it has something to do with the laravel, but I can't find the problem, any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code that I use to perform the update

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $data = $this->validateRequest($request);

        $question = Question::where('id', $id)->first();
        $question->update($data);

        return response()->json([
            'question' => $question,
            'status' => 'Question has been updated'
        ]);
    }

    public function validateRequest($request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'content' => 'required',
            'next' => 'nullable',
            'order' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            throw(new ApiInvalidRequestData($validator->errors()));
        }

        return $validator->validated();
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the specific code which performs update

Comment: One more thing can you print the content of `$request` and `$data` after it is being passed by the validator

Comment: Hmm, it's become "null" instead of null before and after the validation, and I already checked the frontend that giving request, it clearly stated as null not "null" on the frontend.

Comment: So in the end query expression is like ``next` = 'null'` while it should be ``next` = null`. Hope that gives you a clue to resolve this issue

Comment: can you show us the request payload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem as me in the future, in my case, the problem is FormData object that posted with Axios convert every value to a string, including null value, so null value become "null", and it makes an error when saving it to the database. The problem is not the laravel but on the javascript at the frontend, well the laravel is still weird cause it's saying the query generated is ... `next` = **null** ... instead of ... `next` = **"null"** ...